# Python script reading an Excel file stops executing in Task Scheduler

Tags: python-2.7, win32com, import-from-excel

A python 2.7 script, executed by Task Scheduler running on Windows Server 2012 (64 bit), ends without raising an exception at the point where it is opening an existing XLS file. Creating the Dispatch works fine (try/except not shown):

```
xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
```

but right after that:

```
try:
    log_message("Opening Excel Workbook object for the attachment using password '%s'" % email_found['PASSWORD'])
    workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(attachment, False, False, None, email_found['PASSWORD'])
    log_message("Workbook opened, produced object with type '%s'" % type(workbook).__name__)
except Exception, e:
    log_message("Exception opening workbook")
    message = "Exception raised : %s" % str(e)
    log_message(message, 'ERROR')
    xlApp.Quit()
    return 22
```

log_message() writes to a log file and optionally sends an email. The first message appears, and that's the end of the log file. Excel shows up as running in Task Manager, and the task shows as running in Task Scheduler.

The very same script, when run in a command shell by the same user, completes successfully. The very same script, when run in Task Scheduler on a Win7 box, completes successfully.

Other information:

1. The user whose account runs the task is a local administrator. I have tried two such users, and the same thing happens for both.
2. There is only the one instance of Excel (2010) installed on the box.
3. The file whose full path is in 'attachment' definitely exists, and can be opened interactively by Excel.
4. The string stored at email_found['PASSWORD'] contains the correct password for the XLS file.
5. I found some posts that mention the necessity of having one or the other (or both) of these directories:
   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
   Both are present for me (they're empty).
6. I'm running this script on Windows, rather than using xlrd on our preferred Linux platform, because xlrd does not support password protected XLS files. The XLS file is sent to us every week day by a client.

Any suggestions are most welcome, and thanks in advance.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/579900/214926

Comment: 'attachment' is a full path to the XLS file; I will cook up a non-password protected version of this. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I have run a subset of the code against a non password-protected XLS file. The same thing happens : execution stops at the point of the call to xlApp.Workbooks.Open()

Comment: I have tested this using password-protected and non password-protected files, stored on both local disk and server shares (accessed with UNC names). The script works as long as the XLS file is locally stored. Chasing that, I found this post on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/622507/windows-task-scheduler-wont-run-file-on-non-system-drive)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But when I configured the task in *TaskScheduler*, I changed the configuration from "run whether the user is logged on or not" to "run when the user is logged on". And it worked! My script went to the OneDrive folder and read and extract the data from the selected excel.

Comment: How about adding some code for a demonstration?